# How to connect mysql to my play slick scalaSlickTest file

Tags: mysql, jdbc, playframework, slick, scala-collections

```
object scalaSlickTest extends App {
    val parsedConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(newFile("src/main/resources/Application.conf"))
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load(parsedConfig)
          val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")
          val lines = new ArrayBuffer[ Any ]()
          val employees = TableQuery[ Employees ]

}
```

I am getting the exception below:

[image]

Comment: Please post that exception stacktrace as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: can you check if your conf file is being used or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass your loaded config

```
val db = Database.forConfig("mydb", config)
```

Otherwise `forConfig` uses the default config file, which is `application.conf` (case matters).